# what files/folder must be gitted in a ionic project

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

what files/ folder must be gitted in a ionic project ?

I am a newbie in ionic development and dunno in all these files of a project what is sufficient to keep in a github depot, while some other files can be regenerated if needed during the build command.

[image]

Comment: you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/63084828/5379936
when using capacitor, the android/ios folders will have their own .gitignore files, so you don't have to worry about which files should not go in the repository..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic comes already with a .gitignore file which states which files will be ignored. With this default file, you will, for example, not commit folders such as node_modules which can be regenerated with a simple `npm install`

P.E An example .gitignore from an Ionic Project

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
.tmp
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
$RECYCLE.BIN/

*.log
log.txt
npm-debug.log*

/.idea
/.ionic
/.sass-cache
/.sourcemaps
/.versions
/.vscode
/coverage
/dist
/node_modules
/platforms
/plugins
/www
```

Comment: what about /android & /e2e ?